# Windows CMD (or ConEmu) shortcut/alias to command

Tags: windows, cmd, alias

How can i create a shortcut/alias in windows CMD (or ConEmu).

I am using laravel and there is a command:

```
C:\>php artisan make:migration $var1 --create=$var2
```

How do i make a shortcut/alias so I only have to type e.g.?

```
C:\>mig $var1, $var2
```

Comment: Create `mig.bat` or `mig.cmd` as follows: `@php artisan make:migration %1 --create=%2`. Place the script file to any folder seen in `path`.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great answers.

I created a folder on my C: drive named "scripts".
Then in Environment Variables under Path entered C:\scripts.

Logged out -> Logged In

Created a mig.bat file with:
    @php artisan make:migration %1 --create=%2

Now using:
    C:>mig $var1 $var2
Will execute the code as expected.

After reading the answer of @MichaelBurr I investigated further about Doskey.
Which eventually led me to [aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)) ->info about using alias and the the Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with creating and running a .bat file to run another process is, you can end up running a shell inside a shell.

For Windows, create a file like so (replacing `user_000` to match your %HOMEPATH%):

```
REM this filename:   "C:\Users\user_000\doskey.cmd"
@echo off
doskey art=php artisan $*
```

Then right-click on your favorite Command Prompt Shortcut and select Properties.  In `Target:` change it to this:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /K %HOMEPATH%\doskey.cmd
```

The /K will run your `doskey.cmd` file when opening the CLI.